# Dynamic add row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
$("div.test").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
    $(this).closest("div.test"+idtable).remove();       
    counter -= 1
});
```

is there something wrong?

Comment: If you're having an issue we need to know what the problem is. What is `idtable`? Seeing an example of your HTML is also required in this case

Comment: I don't know. You tell me?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You might also want to read the [Stack Overflow question checklist by Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: `on("click",".ibtnDel",function()`, I think  you need to relocate `.ibtnDel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button is clicked not the div, that's why code not working.

```
$(".ibtnDel").on("click", function (event) {
    // remove the div that has this button been clicked
    $('div.test').has(this).remove(); 
    counter -= 1
});
```

Comment: I know the question is lacking any explanation, but answering without any explanation as well doesn't help.